# Obtaining DC from a tri-phase generator

Tags: rectifier, three-phase

I have a tri-phase generator which outputs AC voltage waveforms (\$R\$, \$S\$ and \$T\$) with 120<sup>o</sup> phase shift between them. I want to rectify these voltages and obtain a single DC voltage.

I designed the circuit below, but I'm not sure whether it will work or not.

[image]

a) **Would this circuit work?** (Importatant, please don't skip.)
b) What are the alternative/better circuits for this purpose?

Answer (score 8):

This is what a 3-phase rectifier bridge looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxPPJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This circuit is different. OP circuit will rectify 230VAC, yours 380VAC so those two circuit output voltage is different.